# Multer storage is not uploading file on server directory

Tags: node.js, express, upload, multer

Multer is not uploading files on server directory below my source code to upload file. file object is created that means when i log **req.files** file are present but not uploading to directory.im using POSTMAN for API Testing  sending file through **formdata->uploadfiles** and with key **"uploadfiles"** **destinition function** is not called because l**og inside function** is not console the name **"Hello "**

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        console.log("Hello Umesh");
        cb(null, '../resources/uploads'); // Absolute path. Folder must exist, will not be created for you.
      },
      filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        console.log("Hello Umesh");
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
      }
});

const upload = multer({
                         storage: storage,
                         limit:{filesize:10}

                    }).single('uploadfiles');

router.post('/save', function (req, res) { 
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            res.json({
                success: false,
                message:err
            });
        }
        else{
        res.json({
            success: true,
            message: req.file
        });
    }
    })
});
```

[image: source code files are inside routes]
[image: this is log result when req.files]

Comment: are you sure the directory at `../resources/uploads` exists? (Maybe you want to use __dirname instead of ../ to make sure it's the correct path

Comment: added image where folder exist.my code files inside routes

Comment: does a folder `uploads` exist inside the `resources` folder?

Comment: yes but i wonder console is not printing the message inside destinition folder why?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the absolute path to the storage location:

```
cb(null, require('path').join(__dirname, '..', 'resources', 'uploads'));
```

instead:

```
cb(null, '../resources/uploads');
```

Update:

Since the working directory for functions from the `fs` module is the project's root folder (if you run the project with the `npm start` command), you can simply use this:

```
cb(null, 'resources/uploads');
```

Comment: not working ..but it is not even print log inside destination i think its not called

Comment: @UmeshShende What response does the Postman receive when you send the file?

Comment: success as im getting file object through log  ..but did not upload to directory